# Lag when displaying Video C# XNA

Tags: c#, video, xna, 2d, lag

I'm experiencing several Lags problems when i attempt to display a Background Star Video + some 2D Sprite like : Space Ships, Lasers, Explosions in my Video Game.

Look at these picture to understand what i'm saying :

http://digital-art-studios.e-monsite.com/medias/images/jeu2.jpg

http://digital-art-studios.e-monsite.com/medias/images/jeu4.jpg

When i play the game, move my ships or make explode some asterdoids.
There are some very unpleasant freez, which ruin the pleasure of playing.

Could you tell me why does this happen ??

Thank you :)

Comment: Currently this is to broad of a question. It can be due to poor coding / trying to update and/or draw to many times per second / etc... 
Also trying to see lag with a pic is simply not possible.

Comment: this isn't due to bad coding,
When i disable the video in background.
The game is perfectly smooth with no lags.
When i enable the video several freez are appearing..

Comment: What is the code you are using to play/display your video?

Answer (score 0):

This is The code :

Declaration :

```
    Video video;
    VideoPlayer player;
    Texture2D videoTexture;
```

LoadContent :

```
   video = Content.Load<Video>(@"VIDEOS\VIDEO_BACKGROUND_LEVEL_1");
   player = new VideoPlayer();
```

Update :

```
   if (allVariable.fenetre_Niveau_1_Wolf_359 == true || 
   allVariable.fenetreAfficherStats == true) //Background LEVEL 1
        {

            if (player.State == MediaState.Stopped || allVariable.enablePause == false)
            {
                player.IsLooped = true;
                player.Play(video);
            }

            if (allVariable.enablePause == true)
                player.Pause();
        }
```

Draw :

```
if (allVariable.fenetre_Niveau_1_Wolf_359 == true || allVariable.fenetreAfficherStats == true)
        {

            spriteBatch.Draw(allVariable.backgroundAntibug, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1600, 900), Color.White);

            // Only call GetTexture if a video is playing or paused
            if (player.State != MediaState.Stopped)
                videoTexture = player.GetTexture();

            // Draw the video, if we have a texture to draw.
            if (videoTexture != null)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(videoTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1600, 900), Color.White);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, playing a video while having several objects over it is a bad idea as it is really intensive for the system to process.

Instead of using a video (I assume you are using it to show how the starts are moving on the back), why not create it with code?

You can do so by creating a map and then moving your character above it, or make a huge map and a camera that contanstly moves over it; forcing your player to stay within the camera borders. With that, you can achieve the same effect of the stars moving but without hurting performance.

If creating a huge map + camera is out of the question, for whatever reason, you can create an autoscrolling background which is a Texture2D that constantly moves on the background.

The autoscrolling option is the easiest one and you can check how to implement one [here](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/scrollinga2dbackground/ScrollingA2DBackground.shtml).

Comment: "(I assume you are using it to show how the starts are moving on the back)"

- YES, but as you can see on the gif preview :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k112eaz6sksd438/preview_back_star.gif
(Download it if you don't see the annimation)

i have several "layers" of stars, which give a 3D depth.
and i don't want to loose this because i'm using a simple 2D Texture.

Comment: @Husker Oh but you won't lose it! You can have as many 2d layers as you want, one over the other. The idea would be: 1 black layer at the bottom, and from there... 4 or 5 layers with stars only (transparent background). That way, you get the same effect. All you have to do is implement the autoscrolling on the "stars" textures and that's it. Check the spritebatch.Draw overloads, I believe that all of them, except for the basic one, have a float parameter that is the depth of the item you draw, allowing you the desired effect.

Comment: Ok, thank's for the idea. i'll do it with the Transparent method :)